# Mouse Over function not working for first time after page Load

Tags: jquery, mouseover, tooltip

I have this function where I need to show tooltip when the mouse is hover:

```
  content.live({
            mouseover: function () {
                if (settings.showButtons == false) {
                    content.hover(function () {
                        $('#' + settings.toolTipId).remove();
                        content.attr({ title: '' });
                        buildTipify();
                        positionTipify();
                    }, function () {
                        removeTipify();
                    });
                }
            },
```

But when the page is loaded for the first time it dosen't popup and if I click anywhere on the page and If I mouse over my link then the poup is showing up.

I think the hover function inside hover may be is the one which makes scribble :(

Can anyone point out what am I doing wrong?

Here is my [fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qxDhK/)

Comment: On what should you hover on to show the tooltip. According to your code, the tooltips are showing right. You have the plugin on all your anchor tags, and they show the tooltip on hover or on click

Comment: @DG3-They are working well.But on page load If you directly mouse over the anchor tags they do not show up for the first time and from second time if you click anywhere on the page they show up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you only bind the hover event (technically mouseenter + mouseleave) when in the mouseover event for `content`. So the first time, there is no hover event binded, second time, there is so your tooltip shows.

Honnestly, I don't really understand the whole thing with .live() you're doing:
- why would you use event delegation on an element (content) that exists and remains ?
- why do you only bind your events (click or hover) under mouseover and mouseleave. It just makes no sense...

Here is how I would simply do it. Completely remove the .live() call and bind directly hover or click event according to `settings.showButtons`:

```
if (settings.showButtons == false) {
    content.hover(function() {
        $('#' + settings.toolTipId).remove();
        content.attr({
            title: ''
        });
        buildTipify();
        positionTipify();
    }, function() {
        removeTipify();
    });
} else {
    content.click(function(el) {
        // remove already existing tooltip
        $('#' + settings.toolTipId).remove();
        content.attr({
            title: ''
        });
        buildTipify();
        positionTipify();
        // Click to close tooltip
        $('#' + settings.closeTipBtn).click(function() {
            removeTipify();
            return false;
        });
        return false;
    });
}​
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/jefuX/)**

*Note: I've changed a bit the CSS for the close button because your button was invisible so I couldn't see it.*

Comment: @Didier-Sorry for the late response-Thanks for your time and it worked well! :)

Answer (score 1):

Your guess is correct. The problem is that you are adding `hover` inside the `mouseover` closure. Even worse, you are adding a new `hover` action each time you `mouseover`. If you only want to add the hover when `settings.showButtons == false` then you should just move that outside of your `live`.

Also, it looks like you are going to have the same problem with your `mouseleave` function as well.